# Instructions for fire rescue

Tags: set-identification

I have two sealed bags of LEGO, but I need to find the instructions. The minifigure is a yellow fire rescue guy with a red hat. It has 4 large wheels and 2 bendy yellow hoses. The second bag is a burning tree. I’m not positive they go together. It looks like too many pieces to be the ATV and not enough to be the fire truck, but I can’t find any other yellow fire rescue guys. Can anyone help me find the instructions?

Comment: None of 60105 (white hat though), 30361 (black outfit though), or 4427 have hoses. As always, I would recommend some nice, clear, close-up photos.

Comment: Please add pictures. They usually contain much more information than  you have described.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description (two yellow flexible hoses, yellow minifig with red hat, burning tree) and after digging through bricklink sets (narrowing down the sets that have two yellow flex hoses), I'm fairly certain that you've got parts of [4209-1 Fire Plane](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4209-1):

[image: Set image]

Armed with that set number, it's trivial to find the instructions at https://www.lego.com/service/buildinginstructions/4209 .